# URQL + React "typeError: Cannot read property '_react' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, graphql, urql

I'm currently working through a urql+react tutorial found [here](https://www.howtographql.com/react-urql/0-introduction/) while also adding graphQL API calls to my own application.

In the tutorial the following code is provided to send a query to the server and render components based on the result

```
const FEED_QUERY = gql`
  {
    feed {
      links {
        id
        createdAt
        url
        description
      }
    }
  }
`

const LinkList = () => {
  const [result] = useQuery({ query: FEED_QUERY })
  const { data, fetching, error } = result
  
  if (fetching) return <div>Fetching</div>
  if (error) return <div>Error</div>
  
  const linksToRender = data.feed.links

  return (
    <div>
      {linksToRender.map(link => <Link key={link.id} link={link} />)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

this code runs correctly when I implemented the tutorial myself but when I try to add this exact code to my own application I get the following error(s)

[image: Text]

I have triple checked to make sure all the necessary urql and graphql dependencies are all installed in my application so I'm not sure what could be causing this issue.

Comment: Did you find anything ? I got the same issue.

Comment: Nevermind ! I was refactoring apollo to urql and I left the prop client to Provider instead of value :)

Comment: @bulby97 Thanks - lifesaver!

Comment: Thanks. Same issue here!